# Distribution looks roughly normal on a q-q plot, but has a p-value of 0.0 for the Shapiro-Wilk normality test. How to interpret?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, qq-plot

The distribution is as follows:

[image]

However the Shapiro-Wilk test yields a p-value of 0.0 and a W statistic of 0.9. There are over 7,000 values in the sample.

Note, the  quantile values have been standardized via z-scores.

Is the data roughly normally distributed but the p-value is low because of the very large sample?

Comment: Even ignoring the statistical test, I'd be curious to hear you out on that qq-plot looking "roughly normally distributed".

Comment: Maybe it isn’t normally distributed, need some help interpreting

Comment: Interpretation depends on context: why are you comparing your data to a Normal distribution?

Comment: See my extensive comments on your previous post. I believe this question is largely addressed there.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the detailed answer

Comment: If there are remaining issues, you might edit this one to focus on them